# csv file into array , translation system for a site

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I need help to solve this problem:

I have a csv file like this

hello,ciao
goodbye,arrivederci

as you can see I try to create a translation system for a site
now I want this csv file into an array, the resultant array must be the same of $langArray

```php
<?php $langArray = array([it]=>array([hello]=>ciao,[goodbye]=>arrivederci)); ?>
```

I already have a solution using a Json file to have an array like this, and is most usefull that a csv file and I can use translation system also with javascript. but I want to know the way to do that with a csv file thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reading a CSV file you should use [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) and [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv), or for the short version [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) (needs current PHP or compat library):

```
 $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("it.csv"));
```

Then building the associative map requires a manual loop:

```
 foreach ($csv as $line)
     $translate["it"][ $line[0] ] = $line[1];
```

Comment: note the short version will fail if a column value contains a new line character, even if its properly enclosed with delimiters/quotes.

Comment: into CSV files will be stored only single words or single-line phrases,  very short phrases. for complex translation will be use mysql database. thank you @chris

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split your data once for the new line, then once for the comma, and fill an array with it.

```
<?php
    $translations = array();
    $data = 'hello,ciao
        goodbye,arrivederci';
    $words = explode("\n", $data);
    foreach($words as $w) {
        $parts = explode(',', $w);
        $translations[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    }
    print_r($translations);
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/gCKoI9

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$languageArray = ARRAY();

$my_csv_it = 'hello,ciao goodbye,arrivederci';

$tmp_array_it = explode(' ', $my_csv_it);


foreach ($tmp_array_it AS $text) {
  $pairs = explode(',',$text);
  $languageArray['it'][$pairs[0]] = $pairs[1];
}

print_r ($languageArray);

?>
```